# Add a directive in the link function of another directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm writing a full suite of Web Controls in AngularJS.
Now, I have created a first basic directive a button, which looks like the following:

```
officeWebControls.directive('officeButton', ['$q', 'stylesheetInjectorService', function($q, stylesheetInjectorService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            isDefault: '@',
            isDisabled: '@',
            api: '=',
            label: '@'
        },
        template: OFFICE_BUTTON_TEMPLATE,

        /**
         * @description
         * Provides the controller for the 'officeButton' directive. In this controller all the required methods
         * are being stored.
         */
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
}],

        /**
         * @kind                    Directive caller
         *
         * @param scope             The scope which is passed to the directive.
         * @param element           The element on which this directive is being applied.
         * @param attributes        The attributes that are applied on the element on which this directive is
         *                          applied.
         * @param controller        The controller for this directive.
         */
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
        }
    };
}]);
```

Please note that the most of the code is removed for reading purposes.

Now, I do have another directive, which contains a couple of buttons, but the amount of buttons is defined through a property on the scope.

So I have the following directive:

```
officeWebControls.directive('officeMessageBox', ['$q', 'stylesheetInjectorService', function($q, stylesheetInjectorService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            title: '@',
            message: '@',
            messageBoxStyle: '@',
            messageBoxButtons: '@'
        },
        template: OFFICE_MESSAGE_BOX,

        /**
         * @description
         * Provides the controller for the 'officeButton' directive. In this controller all the required methods
         * are being stored.
         */
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
```

}],

```
        /**
         * @kind                    Directive caller
         *
         * @param scope             The scope which is passed to the directive.
         * @param element           The element on which this directive is being applied.
         * @param attributes        The attributes that are applied on the element on which this directive is
         *                          applied.
         * @param controller        The controller for this directive.
         */
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, controller) {
            // Adds the correct image that defines the style of the button.
            $(messageBoxStyleContainerElement).append(messageBoxStyleElement);

            var messageBoxButtonsElement = '';
            var messageBoxButtonsContainerElement = $('.messageBox-buttons-container', element);

            // Make the necessary adaptations based on the scope.
            switch (scope.messageBoxButtons) {
                case 'messageBoxButtons.Ok':
                    messageBoxButtonsElement = '<data-office-button label="Ok"></data-office-button>';
                    break;
                case 'messageBoxButtons.OkCancel':
                    messageBoxButtonsElement = '<data-office-button label="Ok"></data-office-button>';
                    messageBoxButtonsElement += '<data-office-button label="Cancel"></data-office-button>';
                    break;
                case 'messageBoxButtons.YesNo':
                    messageBoxButtonsElement = '<data-office-button label="Yes"></data-office-button>';
                    messageBoxButtonsElement += '<data-office-button label="No"></data-office-button>';
                    break;
                case 'messageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel':
                    messageBoxButtonsElement = '<data-office-button label="Yes"></data-office-button>';
                    messageBoxButtonsElement += '<data-office-button label="No"></data-office-button>';
                    messageBoxButtonsElement += '<data-office-button label="Cancel"></data-office-button>';
                    break;
            }

            $(messageBoxButtonsContainerElement).append(messageBoxButtonsElement);
        }
    };
}]);
```

So, in the link fuction I'm adding an element `data-office-button` which is in fact a directive.
Now, the problem is that that directive is not compiled, the data-office-button isn't replaced with the correct HTML (like defined in the first template).

Any idea on how that can be accomplished?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that you're using `$` to parse the messageBoxButtonsElement. Try `angular.element` instead.

Alternatively, use a `template` and encode your switch/case logic as a series of `ng-if` statements.

Comment: I have tried some things around and it seems that I has to use angular.element so I'll accept this as an answer. Keep in mind that `$compile(messageBoxButtonsElement)(scope);` was also needed to ensure it's compiled.